# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{na_n}=a$ , then $\lim_{n \to \infty}[n(\frac{{a_{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n+1}-\frac{{a_{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n})]=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, radicals, factorial, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 1 } $ be an unbounded, positive sequence of real
>   numbers, such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{na_n}=a, $ then
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\left(\frac{{a_{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n+1}-\frac{{a_{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\right)=0$$

Of course, the sequence being unbounded and of positive, real, numbers, $a > 0$, and I have managed to obtain, from Cauchy's Criterion, that $ \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} (\frac{{a_n}}{n!})^{\frac{1}{n}}=a, $ and, further, by using Stirling's limit, obtaining $ \lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} \frac{{a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}=a $ is quite straight-forward.
A particular example, which verifies the given property, $a_n= a^n n!,$ indeed verifies the limit-to-be-proven.

This is all (which is relevant) that I've managed to obtain regarding this problem, any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure it is $a_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and not $a_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$? It looks strange.

Comment: @Atticus i am sure, yes.

Comment: I get $\infty$ as well, not $0$.

Comment: At first, I needed to calculate $ \lim_{n \to \infty } (a_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n}} - a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}), $ and I reduced that limit to this one. Is $ \lim_{n \to \infty } (a_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n}} - a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}) = +\infty $ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed I too have obtained now the $\infty$ for the limit in my question, working the answer out for what @Atticus suggested is harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac {a_{n+1}}{na_n} = \frac {a_{n+1} (n-1)!} {a_{n} n!} = \frac {a_{n+1}/n!} {a_{n} / (n-1)!} \sim a \quad  [n \to +\infty].  
$$

Let $b_n = a_n/(n-1)!$, then $b_{n+1} / b_n \sim a$. For $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $N \in \Bbb N^*$ that $a + \varepsilon > b_{n+1}/b_n > a - \varepsilon $ whenever $n \geqslant N$. WLOG we just assume that $N = 1$. Then $b_{n+1}/b_1 \in ((a- \varepsilon)^n, (a+\varepsilon )^n)$, which means $(a_{n+1}/(a_1n!))^{1/n} \in (a - \varepsilon, a+ \varepsilon) $. Thus
$$
a_{n+1} \sim a^n a_1 n!. 
$$
Now the target

\begin{align*}
& \qquad n \left( \frac {a_{n+1}^{1/n}} {n+1} - \frac {a_n^{1/n}} n\right)\\
&= n \cdot \frac {a_n^{1/n}} n \left( \left( \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}\right)^{1/n} \cdot \frac n{n+1} -1\right) \\
&= a_n^{1/n} \left( \left( \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}\right)^{1/n} \cdot \frac n{n+1} -1\right) 
\end{align*}
Since

\begin{align*}
&\qquad \left(\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}\right)^{1/n} \cdot \frac n{n+1} -1\\
&= \exp \left( \frac 1n \log \left( \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}\right) - \log \left(1 + \frac 1n\right) \right) - 1 \\
&\sim \exp \left( \frac  {\log n} n + \frac {\log a}n - \frac 1n + o \left( \frac 1n\right) \right) - 1\\
&\sim \exp \left( \frac  {\log n} n + O\left( \frac 1n\right) \right) - 1\\
&\sim \frac {\log n}n, 
\end{align*}
we conclude that 
\begin{align*}
& \qquad n \left( \frac {a_{n+1}^{1/n}} {n+1} - \frac {a_n^{1/n}} n\right)\\
&= a_n^{1/n} \left( \left( \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}\right)^{1/n} \cdot \frac n{n+1} -1\right)\\
&\sim a_n^{1/n} \cdot \frac {\log n}n\\
&\sim a^{(n-1)/n} a_1^{1/n} ((n-1)!)^{1/n} \cdot \frac {\log n}n\\
&\sim a (2 \pi (n-1))^{1/(2n-2)} \left(\frac {n-1} {\mathrm e}\right)^{1 - 1/n} \cdot \frac {\log n}n \tag {Stirling}\\
&\sim \frac a{\mathrm e} \log n\\
&\xrightarrow {n \to +\infty} +\infty. 
\end{align*}

I will leave it here... any discussion is welcomed. But if I was right, then the limit shall be $+\infty$.